What is the shortkey for selecting folder in "Open Folder" dialog in VS Code?
When I open "Open Folder" or "Add folder to workspace" dialog, I want to pick selected folder instead of falling into it. Enter and ctrl+enter just go inside the selected folder. I am using Windows 11.
